# Force running a script using flock?

Tags: shell, flock

If given a lock on a script using flock(), is it possible to make a force run/unlock based on some argument passed to the script?

Comment: flock will not stop anything from running. `flock` is really just *advisory*. So, I don't know how much sense this makes – just don't ask for advise if you don't want it?

Comment: Also, you can not forcely unlock a file. The file is locked by another process, and it will remain locked until the process that originally locked it releases it (or finishes running).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.